# Install dependencies for a dpkg package?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, dpkg

I have a dpkg file that i want to install.

But I get error messages that it is depending on other packages.

I used:

```
dpkg -i file.dpkg
```

Is there a way to install dependencies automatically without having to use apt-get/aptitude (the latest version of this dpkg wasnt available)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a one-off, copy-paste the package names from the `dpkg` error message to an `aptitude install` command line. Otherwise, set up an apt repository for your own package, it's not hard. Here are a few possible methods:

- If this is for Ubuntu, you can [create your own personal package archive](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA). This will make your packages easily available to everyone, so this method is suitable for generally-useful packages but not for in-house stuff.
- You can set up a local repository using [reprepro](http://mirrorer.alioth.debian.org/). It takes a couple of minutes to set up, but after that adding new packages is trivial (`reprepro includedeb mydistribution /path/to/my.deb`).
- Another way to set up a local repository is to use `apt-ftparchive` from the apt-utils package. This is less automated than reprepro.
- If all you're doing is patching or recompiling existing packages, apt-build is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

You might break dependencies but here is a way to fool apt-get to install your own tar ball.
http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-helpers.en.html#s-equivs

Answer (score 0):

Manually installing missing dependencies can be a pain - which is why tools like `gdebi` exist:

`sudo apt-get install gdebi`

`sudo gdebi package.deb`

This should resolve the dependencies, and install them, all in one go. Note that you may need to add repositories to your `apt` sources.