# How do I install a package and its depencies with dpkg?

Tags: linux, package-management, dpkg, deb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install dependencies for a dpkg package?](https://superuser.com/questions/178139/install-dependencies-for-a-dpkg-package)

```
dpkg -i package.deb
```

Doesn't install package if it has not-installed dependencies.

What parameters do I miss to install that package with its dependencies from repository?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you try to install a package like: `dpkg -i package.deb`
, you can execute
`apt-get install -f` to get the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need parameters, just install the dependencies or use a package manager like `apt-get`.